# Looping through the event log and the EventID appears to be wrong on some records

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am looping through the event log of several remote servers and I noticed that the ".EventID" property  returns an incorrect integer

My Code Snippet:

```
 foreach (EventLogEntry entry in log.Entries.Cast<EventLogEntry>().Reverse())
        {
              string EventID = entry.EventID; //this value is sometimes incorrect
        }
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

The eventID my application is pulling is 263169 but the actual eventID is 1025

Any idea as to why this .EventID property is correct only 95% of the time?

Comment: Posibly because of that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlogentry.eventid(v=vs.110).aspx (see remarks) and by the way - it is obsolete...

Comment: Is their an alternative property I can use?  Or is there a way of converting the instanceid into the eventID in C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a76f64c3-a3df-4302-820c-1ad28fdf8103/how-do-i-convert-eventlogentryinstanceid-to-the-simple-event-id-i-see-in-event-viewer?forum=csharplanguage):

Windows event viewer treat EventID as 16-bit integer (at least it's so as I test in WinXP), so you can cast it to UInt16 to display the same ID as in Event Viewer.

```
foreach (EventLogEntry entry in log.Entries.Cast<EventLogEntry>().Reverse())
{
    var EventID = (UInt16)entry.InstanceId;
}
```