# Testing to see if casting (Uint16) on EventID(deprecated) will be valid?

Tags: c#, .net, event-log

old code: `if (eventArguments.Entry.EventID == 1074)`

The EventID is deprecated. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27027505/21567) I can change it to this:
to

```
(UInt16)eventArguments.Entry.InstanceId == 1074
```

I'm trying to make a console application to test this. Can anyone help or give me some guidance?

edit- here is what I have so far and I think it's enough?

```
            Dictionary<string, EventLog> logList = new Dictionary<string, EventLog>();
        foreach (EventLog log in EventLog.GetEventLogs())
            logList.Add(log.LogDisplayName, log);

        foreach (EventLogEntry entry in logList["Application"].Entries)
        {
            long instanceID = entry.InstanceId;
            long eventID = entry.EventID;
            long calculatedEventID = entry.InstanceId & 0x3fffffff;
            //long calculatedEventID = (UInt16)entry.InstanceId;
            if (eventID != calculatedEventID)
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", eventID, instanceID, calculatedEventID);
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("calculatedEventID is {0} ", calculatedEventID);
            }
        }
```

Comment: So, what exactly is your question?

Comment: @Christian.K I edited the question. How would I prove that EventID is same as InstanceId with the cast of (Uint16) for when it is 1074?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to guarantee the result you're looking for, you'll need this:

```
if (eventArguments.Entry.InstanceId & 0x3FFFFFFF == 1074)
```

You can browse the [.NET Framework Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) to find this out. Specifically, [here's](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/EventLogEntry.cs,7a2fd03c1abc84e2) the source code for `EventLogEntry`. This is the code for the `EventID` property:

```
public int EventID {
    get {
        // Apparently the top 2 bits of this number are not
        // always 0. Strip them so the number looks nice to the user.
        // The problem is, if the user were to want to call FormatMessage(),
        // they'd need these two bits.
        return IntFrom(dataBuf, bufOffset + FieldOffsets.EVENTID) & 0x3FFFFFFF;
    }
}
```

Here's the code for `InstanceId`:

```
public Int64 InstanceId {
    get {
        return (UInt32)IntFrom(dataBuf, bufOffset + FieldOffsets.EVENTID);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question and put what code I have so far. Would I have to create an integer from IntFrom()? I am not sure how to set eventArguments to check to see if EventID and InstanceId are the same.

Comment: Your question isn't really clear. If you're trying to prove that casting `InstanceId` to `UInt16` gives you `EventID` then you can stop, because it won't. What it will give you is the lowest 16 bits of `InstanceId`. If you're trying to prove that using `InstanceId & 0x3fffffff` gives you the result that the now deprecated `EventID` used to, you can stop, because it's the same code as the getter for `EventID`. In short, I don't think there's anything to prove here. Let me know if I've missed your point.

Comment: I'm trying to find a replacement code for "eventArguments.Entry.EventID == 1074". So I believe doing "(eventArguments.Entry.InstanceId & 0x3fffffff) == 1074" will work. Correct?

Comment: Replace your old code (`if (eventArguments.Entry.EventID)`) with what I provided (`if (eventArguments.Entry.InstanceId & 0x3fffffff)`) and you will have solved your problem. Ignore the advice about casting to `UInt16`.

Comment: ok, thank you. That is what I noticed in the code I put in the main question.